# Copy value from one input to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to copy the value of the 'name' input to the 'displayName' input when the checkbox is checked. The value appears on the form but when I console.log the displayName value it shows an empty string.

Here's a recreation of the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/copy-value-from-one-input-to-another-m8292y?file=/src/App.js

```js
const [copyNameToDisplayName, setCopyNameToDisplayName] = useState(false);

  const handleCheckboxChange = () => {
    setCopyNameToDisplayName(!copyNameToDisplayName);
    if (!copyNameToDisplayName) {
      const nameInput = document.getElementById("name");
      const displayNameInput = document.getElementById("displayName");
      if (nameInput && displayNameInput) {
        displayNameInput.value = nameInput.value;
      }
    }
  };

console.log(getValues("displayName"));
```

```js
<Input id="name" {...register("name")} />
  <Checkbox ml={4} onChange={handleCheckboxChange}>
    <Text>Use as display name</Text>
  </Checkbox>
<Input id="displayName" {...register("displayName")} />
```

Comment: You'll need to switch to [controlled components](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/usecontroller) with react-hook-form and set the value in react-hook-form's state.

Answer (score 0):

Used a simplier function to achieve this:

```js
const { control, getValues, setValue } = useForm();

const handleCopyValue = () => {
    const sourceValue = getValues('name');
    setValue('displayName', sourceValue);
  };
  
 <Controller name="name" control={control} render={({ field }) => (
   <Input {...field} /> )}
 />

  <Checkbox onChange={handleCopyValue} />
  
 <Controller name="displayName" control={control} render={({ field }) => (
   <Input {...field} /> )}
 />
```